# position of absolute div after scrolling

Tags: html

I have a div which has like 200 lines of data (goes of the page). this div is positioned using css position:absolute.

After scrolling down, I would like to get the position of top of this div. currently it is giving me 0. which is wrong according to me as its outside the viewable screen area. it should be some negative numbers right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the position is still 0, because that is where you positioned it. The top of the document is where 0 is, not the top of the current viewport. I think what you want is the `window.scrollY`, which will tell you how far down the page the user has scrolled from the top. The negative of this (`-scrollY`) will provide you the number you want.

Comment: @quickLearner No one likes writing cross-browser javascript code. We use polyfills for these sorts of things generally. In JQuery, you can always use `$(window).scrollTop()`, for instance.